# Are sockets reused on reconnect event?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, reconnect

A socket is created when a user connects to the server.

The connection is broken because of interwebz malfunction.

Client reconnects automatically.

Will the socket connection be the same as when he first connected? Or will the socket be a new one?

Thanks!

Comment: It will be new connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new connection is established on reconnect. It can be checked by printing the socket.id.

On server:

```
var io = require('socket.io)(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('socket id is ' + socket.id); }
```

[Excerpt from socket.io documentation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client#socketidstring)

> The property is present once the socket has connected, is removed when the socket disconnects and is updated if the socket reconnects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to preserve state following reconnects in an electron app (e.g. if the host gets suspended then resumed, socket.io gets disconnected).

I haven't tried this yet, but the following article discusses how to reuse socket id's across reconnects. I'll update if I have any success:
https://newbedev.com/reuse-socket-id-on-reconnect-socket-io-node-js

Comment: What happened here - I was unsuccessful implementing the above method - although the socket id could be passed across the reconnect, the actual socket still ended up with a different id for reasons internal to socket.io. Also, a new socket object was created which meant that event listeners on the socket object were no longer attached, so a truly transparent reconnect did not seem possible using socket.io.

Comment: Instead, I removed socket.io client and server and wrote my own implementation using the raw browser websockets with ws (https://github.com/websockets/ws) on the server. I also used an RPC mechanism, similar to that used to pass callbacks over a postmessage type interface. It makes less network requests, less code and 3rd party modules and reconnects work perfectly and can be made completely transparent, so to the client, it looks it's always connected. It seems transparently reconnecting seems to be a bit of a problem with socket.io, and it had to work, so I had to get rid of it.